# is there any java SDK available to implement google-dfp ads for J2ME?

Tags: java-me, ads, google-dfp

Is there any way to implement google-dfp ads for J2ME platform? I  have tried few things using following link and I am not getting anything. Can anyone help me out in this?

http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1638620

Comment: According to the link you provided only mob=js parameter is required for mobile requests, but you should also use the optional parameters. Please edit your question with the parameters you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

seems till now its only for android ,ios and windows mobile. you can have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#incorporating)